# VPN not connecting after resuming from standby on Vista home premium

Tags: windows-vista, vpn

I am having windows vista home premium OS on my laptop. I am having a windows VPN setup too. All of a sudden my vpn doesnt work when my PC resumed from stand by mode. I tried all options but still I am getting that error.

CoId={5B82082D-9236-4AF9-900B-4E8072341C76}: The user workgroup\user dialed a connection named VPNName which has failed. The error code returned on failure is 0.

I am also getting the following error when I verified the event logs
The user workgroup\user dialed a connection named VpnName which has failed. The error code returned on failure is 800.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Stand-By is a slightly-deglorified turn off mode.

All network connections are killed when going into Stand By - so the VPN will be as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using wireless, it might help to use the Maximum Performance setting:

1. Go to Control Panel / Power options / Change plan settings / Change advanced power settings.
2. Open Wireless Adapter Setting, then open Power Saving Mode.
3. If the setting is not at Maximum Performance, click to change.

Answer (score 0):

For [a list of error codes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923944), see [r0ca's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/110640/why-wont-my-vpn-connect/110643#110643) at "Why won’t my VPN connect?" here at Super User.

> 800: Unable to establish the VPN connection. The VPN server may be unreachable, or security parameters may not be configured properly for this connection.